# IOS Open New View controller Programatially

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need to open a registration form on my application programatically, the view controller is created  on  storyborad with storybpard ID `ViewControllerRegister` and the code I have used to open the form is

```
RegistrationFormViewController *registerView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerRegister"];
          [self presentViewController:registerView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

But when I run the application, I am getting the error like,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
>       *** First throw call stack:

Comment: Have u added the storyboard id as similar.

Comment: Yes the name is ViewControllerRegister.

Comment: no problem not in RegistrationFormViewController here , check after the present you were add some nil value to your array , that the error

Comment: Make sure you have initialized your array

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Make sure about your storyboardname is "Main" or different.

[image]

**2)** Check you have entered proper storyboard identifier.

[image]

and Finally,

**3)** Sometimes Xcode can't able to find storyboard with  `self.storyboard`.
Try to mention storyboard with actual name like,

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        RegistrationFormViewController *registrationFormViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegistrationFormViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:registrationFormViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Basically my application is slider menu with navigation view controller. I need to pop the registration form if the device not registered on when the application launches. And I have put the above below - `(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];`

Comment: Do you have any demo for that ?

Comment: I am following the tutorial here http://archetapp.com/2014/07/14/how-to-make-a-slide-out-menu-with-objective-c-in-xcode/

Comment: I need to show your code. I can't understand your scenario. You are trying it from side menu or simple your viewcontroller ? and what you want to do ? pop or present ?

Answer (score 1):

> [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil, the error says Look in your code for any lines that say "`insertObject:atIndex:`".  The object you're inserting is apparently nil.

Make sure you have initialized your array called XXXX before adding any object into it...

```
NSMutableArray *xxx=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and stop adding any nil object into it...

```
if(str) //or if(str != nil) or if(str.length>0)
{
//add the str into xxx array.
}
else
{
 //add the empty value to your xxx array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in your code for loading a view controller programmatically. You must check with breakpoint that either your `viewDidLoad` method is being called in your opening controller or not. If it is being called then everything is fine and you need to check what you are doing in your opening controller's life cycle methods.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will cross check it.